# Syntax Error when attempting to import aws\ssm-parameters in nodes on a lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops

I have an issue with aws nodejs sdk with AWS Lambda. From the official documentation im trying to fetch aws\ssm-parameters with lambda.

Doc: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ssm/classes/getparameterscommand.html

And this is my Lambda code

```
import { SSMClient, GetParametersCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ssm"
const config = { region: "eu-central-1"}


exports.handler = async (event, context) => {


const client = new SSMClient({ region: config.region});
const command = new GetParametersCommand({Names: ["/my-app/dev/db-url"]});
const response = await client.send(command);

console.log(response);
};
```

But when run aws lambda function it through error to me as below:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
"errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
```

I am really new in JS world. Anybody know why its complaining ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ssm/index.html) use the ES5 syntax:

```
const { SSMClient, GetParametersCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-ssm");
```

Lambda currently only supports ES5 and for SDK version 3 you will need to install the modules as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/lambda-create-table-example.html).
Locally you need:

```
npm install @aws-sdk/client-ssm
```

For SDK V2 this will do:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ssm = new AWS.SSM();
const val = await ssm.getParameter(
    {Name: '/my-app/dev/db-url'}).promise();
console.out(val);
```

Comment: I tried this also got different error: 
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-ssm'"

Comment: Please see my edited answer